# Finding absolute url of img tag

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

I'm using `Node.js` and `cheerio` for web scraping and currently have a situation where I can't extract absolute url of `img` tag.

So here's the code:

```
$('.images').each(function () {
  console.log("absolute url: " , $(this)[0].src)
});
```

I'm getting back `undefined` for the `src` value running that code inside Node.js, however when I apply that code directly in the Chrome console, works fine.Seems like `Node.js` didn't implement src property ? Next I tried to output properties of `$(this)[0]`

```
{
  "type": "tag",
  "name": "img",
  "attribs": {
    "class": "images",
    "src": "/gfx/image.png",
    "alt": "",
    "children": [],
    "next": {
      "data": "\r\n        ",
      "type": "text",
      "next": null,
      "prev": "[Circular]",
      "parent": {} 
    }
  }
}
```

Really, it doesn't have `src`, only `attrbs.src` which returns relative url, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `img` probably doesn't have an absolute url but only the reletive one. `attribs.src` is *the* `src`. But you know which site you are scraping, so you can build the absolute url.

```
absoluteUrl = 'domain.com' + attribs.src;
```

Comment: Yeah, I'll go with that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the predicted behaviour as stated in the documentation linking to http://api.jquery.com/attr/.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add some code examples to your answer. Whereas a link to the official docs is very welcome, some code can help inexperienced users understand and also makes it easier for future visitors to find an answer faster. Thanks